# Can I include Javascript/jQuery in a page?

Tags: pages, jquery, javascript

I'm extremely new to Wordpress, and I've offered to help out with a project that uses it.

In a new page I'm creating, I need to use javascript/jQuery to write out the html dynamically - it doesn't seem to be working? I believe I read there was something special that needed to be done, but I can't figure out. I tried changing the `$` to `jQuery`, but that didn't work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('hoi');
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "link-here",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {alert(CSVToArray(data));}
        error: function(){ alert('error');}
     });
</script>
```

I have this at the top - the `alert` isn't even called. How can I get this working?

**Edit** It looks like jQuery is loaded for all but the admin page - correct?

```
//jQuery Insert From Google
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

**Edit Two** It looks like the code I wrote is being wrapped in `<p>` tags. This must mean that the script doesn't belong in the `New Page`. Where should the code go?

Comment: do you have access to the theme functions.php?

Comment: I do. I can make changes to it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvotes are probably for the lack of research effort. If you search our site for `include jquery` you will find the answer.

Comment: My question was about including it in a page - not a page template. I couldn't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that jQuery is loaded, so that you can use it.

In functions.php:

```
function namespace_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( is_page( 'slug-of-new-page-you-are-creating' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namespace_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Made an edit to my post

Comment: I agree, it looks like jQuery is loaded in the front end, and not in the back end.

Comment: So what is it I need to do?

Comment: Do you have `<php wp_head(); ?>` somewhere in your header.php?

Comment: yes, I do - is there something needed in the new page besides putting the code in a `script` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I feel dumb. The problem was how I was putting the script into the page.

This solved my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
 alert('hoi');
 //--><!]]></script>
```

[Using Javascript](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)